# How to align text center with unordered list without text warping?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*I like to show a unordered list text center of image background at top. But unfortunately, i am getting the text warpped. I don't know why it happens. Please fix my code.*

**My code,**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
.image {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}
.title {
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.title ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    letter-spacing:0px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">     
<img src="image.jpg" class="image">
 <div class="title" >
        <ul>
            <li>S</li>
            <li>o</li>
            <li>m</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>T</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>x</li>
            <li>t</li>
            <li>H</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>r</li>
            <li>e</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Output,** fig1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zHnW.jpg

*(fig1 : This above image was edited using photo editor to show my expected output)*

**But, Output i am getting,** fig2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzMeW.jpg

*(fig2 : This above image is the screenshot of orginal output i am getting actually)*

**I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please fix my code and explain. My need is, List to be shown in center of the image background in same line without warping.**

Comment: Do you mean warping or wrapping?

Comment: text warping (I don't want letters skip to next line. Need it to be in single line and center of the image ..as shown in expected output) @j08691

Comment: Iiiiim pretty sure  you mean wrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each letter of your word are in individual `<li>` tags, one thing that might fix this is the following.

```
.container .title ul {
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

It would also be beneficial here to add the following css:

```
.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will size the container of the title to fit the entire screen, which at the moment it isn't.

Also, from your demo page, you still need to add `display: flex;` to your `<ul>`.

From what I'm seeing in the inspector - doing these things should fix your problem.

Comment: That works on desktop site.. But not on mobile view :( as i added the first line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` i expected it to be in mobile view :( as well as in desktop view too..

Comment: Can you show me what it looks like on mobile? Do you have any media queries?

Comment: And again works good in desktop view :( not in mobile view... in mobile view its still get warped as shown in the expected output... i have made a demo page for this code u can check here » http://phlab.16mb.com/

Comment: That works.. Now the view is way better than before.. But, its slightly had more gap at left than right. like not a proper centerised text. (like 1 cm gap on left before text and only 0.5cm gap on right after text) pls take a look at same page again i updated the code which u posted.

Comment: from the demo page, ul still needs display: flex; and you need to add padding-left: 0; I think you're missing the semi-colon after display: flex on your <ul>

Comment: That's Perfect.  Added semicolon and added `padding-left: 0;` and boom its pefectly center as per my need in both mobile and desktop .. No words to say bro... Thanks a lottttttt ❤️